# How to redirect if user already logged in

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have a login script that does this:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;

$_SESSION['password']=$password;
```

If the user logged in succesfully. 
And so I edited the signup page to do this:

```
<?php

function redirect() {
    header(' URL= index.php');
}

?>
<?php session_start(); ?>  

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class=" no_js">
<head>
 <link href='icon.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
 <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
 <Title>Sign up | JMToday</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   redirect();
  }
?>
```

But it doesn't redirect the user when I logged in with my account that I created. Why is that?

Comment: the idea here is that you accept the answer that solves your question. I've noticed that you haven't accepted any of your questions here. Please do that, as you'll more likely get good answers if you award the people who help you.

Comment: Did you try to enable warnings? You should be getting _Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent..._

Comment: How many times have you posted this nearly identical code sample over the past few days? Please follow some of the advice you've be given by people and stop re-posting this until you've at least a clue about what you're doing.

Comment: Dont store the password in a session... use a token something that doesn't give away all of a user credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function redirect() {
    header('location:index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
header(' URL= index.php');
```

should be

```
header ( 'Location: index.php' );
```

Also you might want to put a `die()` statement after the call to `header()` so that you stop the execution of your script completely.

And you should probably move the call to `redirect()` above any other output since HTTP headers must be the first thing in the response. It's possible that this is also the cause of your problem.

Comment: can you replace probably with obligatory? he has too, otherwise it won't work at all

Comment: @Hannes he might have `output buffering` turned on hence "probably" :)

Comment: defining a function in a `ob`  ? That would be even worse :D

Comment: @Hannes output buffering can be turned on in php.ini and works "automagically".

Comment: *shrugs* still bad style thou

Comment: @Hannes I agree, but this may or may not be the case here, so I have to take it into account :)

Comment: I however don't put the `die()` or `exit()` in my code. I ensure that all my code is properly inside the `if()` or `else` conditions and there is nothing which can execute after the redirection happens. I keep my main controller code mostly consisting of function calls one after the other so that there is not too much of lines of code and the scope of the `if-else` is easily visible and there is no chance of something executing by mistake and hence no need of putting an `exit` or `die` to ensure that. wanted your opinions people.

Answer (score 11):

Change the `redirect()` function to:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

And move the call to redirect above all the html output:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    redirect();
} ?>
```

From the [`header()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called
>   before any actual output is sent,
>   either by normal HTML tags, blank
>   lines in a file, or from PHP.

This is what it should look like in the end, taking @Jan's advice to add a call to `die()`:

```
<?php
function redirect($DoDie = true) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    if ($DoDie)
        die();
}
php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    redirect();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class=" no_js">
<head>
 <link href='icon.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
 <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
 <Title>Sign up | JMToday</title>
</head>
<body>
?>
```

Comment: I'd move `die()` to the `redirect()` function, so that you don't have to remember to type it every time you do a redirect ...

Comment: @Jan I considered that, but do you want to restrict to being the last thing you ever call? I'm taking into account that you might later use the `redirect()` function elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you could pass a `$DoDie` parameter to the `redirect()` function. Anways, I've never came across a situation where I did a redirect and wanted to execute some code after that. But that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's `header('Location: index.php');`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect immediately, then

```
function redirect(){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

if you want to redirect with some delay, then

```
function redirect(){
    header("Refresh: 0;url=default.php");
}
```

increase the 0 in "Refresh:0" to introduce greater delay.

you might use this to redirect after showing some notification/message to the user.

**Note** if you are having some trouble in redirecting, then put "exit()" at the end of function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if((isset($_SESSION["username"]))) 
  {
   header("Location: home.php");
  }
?>
```