# Redirecting user back to original site after successful contact form PHP

Tags: php, redirect, contact-form

I'm trying to redirect my customers back to my original home page after they successfully enter their contact information.  How would I do that with the following PHP form?  Thanks in advance for all your help!

```
<?php

// Receive form's subject value into php $subject variable
$subject =$_REQUEST['subject'];

// Receive form's message value into php $message variable
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];

// Receive form's sender name value into php $sender variable
$sender=$_REQUEST['name'];

// Receive form's user email value into php $user_email variable
$user_email=$_REQUEST['email'];

// the email address where the message will be sent
$TO ="ttdthemes@gmail.com";

$send_email=mail($TO,$subject,$message,"From: ".$sender."<".$user_email.">");

// To check email has been sent or not
if($send_email)
{
echo "Your E-mail has been sent !";
}
 else
{
echo "E-mail sent was failed !";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect you can use:

```
header("Location: yourpage.php");
```

to redirect to the page you want

Answer (score 0):

Just use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function of php 
// To check email has been sent or not

```
if($send_email)
{
   header('location:youwebsitehomepahe.php');
}
 else
{
   echo "E-mail sent was failed !";
}
```

There are some other similar postings you can refer

[How to redirect if user already logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525576/how-to-redirect-if-user-already-logged-in)